# Azure WinRm Copy Task failing

Tags: azure-devops

I have WinRm copy files task in Azure DevOps release pipeline. It fails with the following error message in the log `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ToSession'.`

[image]

Comment: Which agent are you using? Hosted agent? Or self-hosted agent?

Comment: Self- hosted agent

Comment: Since the agent you are using is self-hosted, it should not caused by access. Do you mind share the full debug log? Very confused about "ToSession".